# Вычисление размера View до его отрисовки Android

Tags: android, view

Хочу сделать динамического размера `ListPopupView`. У него может быть различное количество пунктов, но известно какой из них самый длинный (по тексту). Пусть это будет конкретный пример

```
String[] types = new String[]{"radix", "fructus", "flores", "herba"};
popupAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(context, R.layout.popup_item, types);
selectTypeBTN.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            selectTypeLPV.setAdapter(popupAdapter);
            selectTypeLPV.setWidth(???);
            selectTypeLPV.setHeight(???);
            selectTypeLPV.setAnchorView(view);
            selectTypeLPV.setModal(true);
            selectTypeLPV.show();
        }
    });
```

если интересно - `popup_item.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.iam.herbaldairy.widget.text.Text   
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="6dp"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:id="@+id/popup_text"
    android:textSize="14sp"/>
```

`Text` - обычный `TextView` с собственным `Typeface`
Теперь надо собственно посчитать размеры `ListPopupItem`

```
final Text text = (Text) ((AppCompatActivity) context).getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.popup_item, null);
text.setText("fructus");
text.measure(MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
Log.d("len", text.getMeasuredWidth() + "");
Log.d("len", text.getMeasuredHeight() + "");
```

Затем поместим эти размеры в соответствующие сеттеры `ListPopupView`

```
selectTypeLPV.setWidth(text.getMeasuredWidth() + text.getPaddingLeft() + text.getPaddingRight());
selectTypeLPV.setHeight(types.length * (text.getMeasuredHeight() + text.getPaddingTop() + text.getPaddingBottom()));
```

Кажется всё, запускаем, проверяем и получаем один и тот же результат на разных экранах
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Т.е. длина вычисляется короче, чем нужно, высота больше, чем нужно, отсюда вопрос - что я упустил и что было лишним?

Comment: Что это за `ListPopupView`, собственный виджет? Почему не использовать обычный `PopupMenu`, который сам расчитает нужные размеры?

Comment: @pavlofff https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListPopupWindow.html , опечатался, хотя может и считал что он так называется, автодополнение портит)) Попробую PopupMenu, чуть позже отпишу, что вышло

Comment: @pavlofff PopupMenu решение для выравнивания по вертикали, а вот по горизотали оно шире, чем мне хотелось бы.